# Check if a string contains only a set of letters

Tags: java, string, char

I'm trying to check if a word contains only a set of letters such as I,O,S,H and X
Suppose the user enters: SSHX, the output will be yes but if the user enters SHEXX, the output will be NO

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String word = sc.next();
    word = word.toUpperCase();

    int length = word.length();
    char letter = 0;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < length; counter++) {
        letter = word.charAt(counter);
    }
    if (letter != 'I' && letter != 'O' && letter != 'S' && letter != 'H' && letter != 'Z' && letter != 'X' && letter != 'N') {
        System.out.print("NO");
    } else {
        System.out.print("YES");
    }
}
```

Comment: A regex is the simplest solution, but if you want to know why yours isn't working, it's because you aren't testing anything inside the `for` loop.  You can see this for yourself in the debugger.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a good way of solving it. The problem is that you're not actually checking each letter, so you need to do the checks inside of the for loop or you will only check the last letter. But then you can't print the "YES" as you only want to print it if ALL letters are yes, so you can use a boolean value to check that as well, as such:

```
    boolean isMatch = true; 
    for (int counter = 0; counter < strLength && isMatch; counter++) {
        letter = word.charAt(counter);
        if (letter != 'I' && letter != 'O' && letter != 'S' && letter != 'H' && letter != 'Z' && letter != 'X' && letter != 'N') {
            System.out.print("NO");
            isMatch = false;
        } 
    }
    if (isMatch) {
        System.out.print("YES");
    }
```

But, as others have pointed out using a regular expression is more effective (and this one has a working regex for what you want.. The asterisk means zero or more of what's inside the brackets. ):

```
    if (word.matches("[HIOSX]*")) {
        System.out.print("YES");
    } else {
        System.out.print("NO");
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

```
String regex = "[OSXHI]*";
String string = "SOMETHING";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(string);
if (matcher.find())
{
    String match = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(match);
}
```

Some additional resources:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/
- [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)
- [Regular Expressions - User Guide](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm)

Comment: *Copy pasted comment from the other answer:* Your regex will only match a String of one character (which should indeed be among the listed ones). You need to add a `*` to make it match multi-character words.

Comment: If you will notice, I was the first to answer. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I haven't noticed, sorry... the "copy/pasted" part is for the other answer then... :)

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the obvious answer of using a regular expression, consider using Google's Guava [API](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) to make this pretty simple:

```
if(CharMatcher.anyOf("HIOSX").matchesAllOf(word)) { 

} ...
```

Comment: I think you want it the other way around: `CharMatcher.anyOf("HIOSX").matchesAllOf(word)`

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression:

```
if (word.matches("[HIOSX]+"))
    System.out.println("YES");
else
    System.out.println("NO");
```

Comment: Your regex will only match a String of one character (which should indeed be among the listed ones). You need to add a `*` to make it match multi-character words.

Comment: Thanks. Actually it should be a `+` to prevent empty strings from matching.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should initialize letter like this:
`char letter = '0';` instead of 0
second of all your for loop is badly used try this code:

```
 boolean isInSet;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < strLength; counter++) 
    {
        letter = word.charAt(counter);
        if (letter != 'I' && letter != 'O' && letter != 'S' && letter != 'H' && letter != 'Z' && letter != 'X' && letter != 'N') 
        {
            isInSet=false;
            counter=strlength; //end loop
        } 
        else 
        {
           isInSet=true;
        }
    }
    if(isInSet=true)
    {
       System.out.print("YES");
    }
    else
    {
       System.out.print("NO");
    }
```

Now the loop will loop over the string and check if each character is in the set, if it isnt the loop ends and the boolean is set to false which results in the NO output